# How to access firebase data from wordpress hosted in a remote server?

Tags: mysql, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have developed an android game, it stores user scores in firebase. How do I access the user scores from wordpress website?. Is it possible to create a login for my android app using play store account, and have the play store google account to login to my site to check their score?

Comment: expose an API token (after login), and your app can use the API token to push data to the website. The website feeds this to MySQL after validating the API token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve data from Firebase and display it on the WordPress website.

https://firebase-wordpress-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/retrieve-data-from-firestore.html

There is also an option to log in with Google on a WordPress site, so the user will only see the data based on their security rule.